# How to load multiple cogs in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was making a Discord bot and had to load 2 cogs `cogs/foo.py` and `cogs/fooo.py`. I wanted to load both of them so I did this in my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('UwU')
    bot.load_extension("cogs.foo")
    bot.load_extension("cogs.fooo")
```

This is my cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command()
    def Foo(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send("Foo")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Cog(bot))
```

And, this is the error I get after running my code:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.fooo' raised an error: CommandRegistrationError: The alias n is already an existing command or alias.
```

So, it successfully loads the first cog but raises the error on the second one.

Answer (score 2):

[Maybe this can help?](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be)
Its an example on how to load cogs and how they work.
To load multiple cogs do this:

```py
    for cog in initial_extensions:
        client.load_extension(cog)
```

If you clicked on the link and read through the code you'll know what `initial_extensions` is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
        print("Cog Loaded!")
```

To import more than 1 cogs.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through `os.listdir`

```py
import os

for f in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if f.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{f[:-3]}')
```

Also the error means that there is already a command named `n`, so go through your code and check if every command has a unique name

Comment: Yeah, though I dont have a command or an alias named `n` thats why I was confused. And, its still giving the same error even though I did check my code and there is no command or alias named `e` ;-;.

Comment: Really digging this up, but it should be `os.listdir` in the code, not `os.lisdir`